# $Cov(X-E(X\mid Y), Y) =0$

Tags: covariance

$$Cov(X-E(X\mid Y), Y) =0 $$

Above $Cov$ denotes Covariance.

My textbook says above identity always holds, but I can't figure why it is so.

Any hint or advice?

Also, if $Cov(X-E(X\mid Y), Y) =0 $ always holds, Does $Var(X-E(X\mid Y), Y) =0 $ always hold?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In general
$$Cov(A,B) = E(AB) - E(A)E(B)\,. $$

So $Cov(X - E(X\mid Y), Y)$ is
\begin{align*}
Cov(X - E(X\mid Y), Y) & = E[(X - E(X\mid Y))Y] - E[X - E(X\mid Y)]E[Y] \\
& = E[XY] - E[Y E(X\mid Y)] - E(Y)[E(X) - E(E(X \mid Y))]\\
& = E[XY] - E[ E(XY \mid Y)] - E(Y)[E(X) - E(E(X \mid Y))]\,.
\end{align*}

By the [law iterated expectation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_total_expectation) $E(E(X\mid Y)) = E(X)$ and $E(E(XY \mid Y)) = E(XY)$.

\begin{align*}
Cov(X - E(X\mid Y), Y) & = E[XY] - E[ E(XY\mid Y)] - E(Y)(E(X) - E(E(X \mid Y))\\
& = E(XY) - E(XY) - E(Y)\left[E(X) - E(X) \right]\\
& = 0\,.
\end{align*}

Regarding $Var(X - E(X \mid Y), Y)$, that notation makes no sense.

Comment: thx. I think you missed out Y for the target COV